# delete file on cloudinary using php

Tags: php, cloudinary

My folders on cloudinary...
product/banner
product/profile_pic

I have banners and profile_pictures of items...Now On cloudinary i want to delete particular banner of product....

For uploading my code is like **Which works totally FINE**:

```
public function cloudinary($myfile,$folder)
{      
    $cloudUpload = \Cloudinary\Uploader::upload($myfile["banner"]["tmp_name"] , array("folder" => $folder));
    $cloud_path = $cloudUpload['url'];
    return $cloud_path;
}
```

Now How to delete the image when i am editing product detail?So,I want to perform operation like unlink file from folder ON "CLOUDINARY WITH PHP"

Answer (score 3):

You can delete Image using destroy method:

```
\Cloudinary\Uploader::destroy($id);
```

where `$id` is the id of image. In your case you can get the id from `$cloudUpload['public_id']`

Answer (score 0):

Try looking [here](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#delete_resources) at the API documentation for deleting resources.

Comment: I am not using API I am doing it with PHP code and by including libraries for that...I have tried every way to do that...!! @iJamesPHP

Comment: I would advise using the API for what you're trying to do.